# Testing a DLL with NUnIt-How to know which config file is being used

Tags: .net, nunit, app-config

I have a project having more than one .exe and also having more than one .config files.The project is in .Net Framework and it's windows application. I have built this project for Nunit Testing.I have to define some key in config file. So I want to know that how could I know that which config file is being used by Nunit? There is no app.config file.All config files having name other than app.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the current `Configuration` object:

```
Configuration config =
         ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Then the `config.FilePath` will tell you which .config file is loaded.

**Update:**

The value returned from the `FilePath` property is the default location for the current assembly. As the current assembly is loaded by NUnit, this will not be the location which is normally used by your application.

To solve your problem, you could

- Always load your configuration from a location which you provide:

  `Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);`
- Use NUnit to copy a test config file to the location you find in the file path:

  `File.Copy(testConfigFile, config.FilePath);`
- Use NUnit to set up the key you want to test in the test itself:

  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Add("key", "value");`

Comment: Hi, I haven't found "config.FullPath" but there was a property "config.FilePath".But when I am using config.FilePath property then it's returning the path as dllName+.config (like d:\abc.dll.config)
whereas there is no such type of config file exists. I am running NUnit test by selecting a single dll. So please help me.
Thanks,
Banketeshvar Narayan

Comment: Actually I was using NUnit 2.6 and I found that NUnit 2.6 no longer reads settings from your test configuration file 

I was using these lines which is not working for Nunit 2.6.2.
<configuration> 
    <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
        <section name="TestRunner"  type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <NUnit>
        <TestRunner>
           <!-- The ApartmentState value here is ignored. -->
           <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
        </TestRunner>
      </NUnit>
  </configuration>

Answer (score 2):

Actually I was using NUnit 2.6.2 for unit testing with these lines in .config file

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
       <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" /> 
     </sectionGroup> 
  </configSections> 
  <NUnit> 
    <TestRunner> 
      <!-- The ApartmentState value here is ignored. --> 
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" /> 
    </TestRunner> 
  </NUnit> 
</configuration>
```

But NUnit 2.6 no longer reads settings from your test configuration file. So you need to add attribute [assembly: NUnit.Framework.RequiresSTA] in Assemblyinfo.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create methods to open config file and update the values than save it again. You will have to probably save it in two places because NUnit will not read your actual config file.Than you can use the second one for testing purposes if needed to assert the expected value against the value updated in the file. Also you might wana look into mocking certain outside dependencies. Since NUnit should really be testing the class you are working with.